# JPA basic type ElementCollection computed value in query

Tags: jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

Consider the following Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Parent{

@Column
private String name;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="REF_TABLE",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="REF_COLUMN_ID"))
@Column(name="REF_COLUMN_VALUE")
public Set<String> getValues() {
      return values;
}
}
```

I need to implement JPA criteria where clause for "UPPER(REF_COLUMN_VALUE) IN (?values)"

So far I have :

```
root.joinSet(Parent_.values, JoinType.LEFT).in(collectionOfValues)
```

How can I apply UPPER function for each element in values ?

I know I can achieve this by defining and wrapping String value as  @Embeddable class, that would give me meta-attribute for value property and I could do :

```
joinSet = root.joinSet(Parent_.values, JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaBuilder.isMember(criteriaBuilder.upper(joinSet.get(WrapedString_.value)),criteriaBuilder.literal(collectionOfValues))
```

Can I do it without introducing the wrapper ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case someone interested in :

```
SetJoin<Object, Object> setJoin = root.joinSet(Parent_.values.getName(), JoinType.LEFT);    
CriteriaBuilder.In<String> in = criteriaBuilder.in(criteriaBuilder.upper(setJoin.as(String.class)));
for(String  v:collectionOfValues){
   in.value(v.toUpperCase());
}
```

Don't forget to add *distinct* to your query as LEFT_JOIN is being used.